# GWT Control for creating content

Tags: gwt, widget

I need something like this in GWT for creating content, is it possible,

[image]

Is there any widget or any other ways to use something like this in GWT??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [RichTextArea](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RichTextArea.html), you can find an example of it [in the showcase](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwRichText)

Comment: Yes, when the user is entering the text, I can use a Rich Text Area, but what about when I need to display the text from the database, how do i display it with all its formatting

Comment: You would store the result from yourRichTextArea.getHtml() in the database, if you want to display the text you would call yourRichTextArea.setHtml()

Comment: In the showcase example, there is tab above the textarea that allows the user to customize formatting, Do you know how to add this tab?

Comment: You would need to implement that yourself, here is the code used in the example: [link](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/showcase/src/com/google/gwt/sample/showcase/client/content/text/RichTextToolbar.java?r=4142)